# Embedded code in NavigateUrl of an asp:Hyperlink. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

In code-behind of an ASP.NET page I have this method:

```
public string TestFunc()
{
    return "http://www.blabla.net";
}
```

And in markup this:

```
<%= TestFunc() %>
```

If I run the page I see "http://www.blabla.net" as text on the page and in debugger I enter TestFunc - all as expected.

If I put this Hyperlink on the same aspx page...

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="MyLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%= TestFunc() %>'>Proceed...
</asp:HyperLink>
```

... I don't enter TestFunc in debugger and the generated HTML of the href contains the embedded code simply as text: `href="%3C%=%20TestFunc%28%29%20%%3E"`

What am I doing wrong here? I have already tried stupid trial and error: Replaced `=` by `#`, omitted `=` and replaced single quotation marks `'` by double quotation marks `"`. But all this didn't help. Now I am stumped.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "<% %>" construction within container which supports templates (e.g. GridView with combination of Bind, Eval). Simple usage with properties will cause encode your expression and will display "as is".

Comment: But why does then the first simple example in my question without the HyperLink work? It's not in any asp container.

Comment: Such situation is also allowed.

Comment: Ah OK, I understand. Control properties (outside of container templates) are the problem.

Comment: OK, I have found 2 workarounds for my purpose. 1) In Page_Load: `MyLink.NavigateUrl = TestFunc();` or 2) `<a href="<%= TestFunc() %>">Proceed...</a>`